# How negociate a raise that has been decided?

Tags: salary, negotiation, united-kingdom, raise

### Background

It is soon to be my contract anniversary, so the appropriate timing to negotiate a raise. I work in IT, in a fairly large company. 
 
I am then currently doing my homework (list of achievements, looking at job offers in the area to know current salaries).

I want to ask a ca. 30% raise. This is a lot, but I believe I was underpaid in my initial position (I didn't had the right background, plus they currently have an open position with public salary range). In addition, my role changed and I have started managing a small sub team (2–5 people).

Concurrently, my line manager just let me know during a workplace event the other day that they got me a raise. But they didn't precise how much (timing wasn't appropriate for further discussion).

### Problem

I know that I have been decided for me. I don't know how much. But I suspect it will not be as high as I wish.

### Question

**How to negotiate a higher raise when when its amount will be revealed?**

Indeed, if the raise has already been approved (by my manager's manager  HR), it seems odd to make a fuss again. I know I might/should have been more proactive to lead the discussions. But my question is about how to deal with the cards I currently have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that has actually worked for me in the past is to say that you believe you need your salary to be readjusted, not just raised. I was asking for a bit less (15% increase) whereas the typical raise was around 2%. I laid out some research I had done on industry salary for similar positions and also researched the company pay scale and found out I was on the lower end of that scale despite being a good performer (I was recently promoted). Those arguments were the foundation of that discussion on salary readjustment. That discussion was met initially with some pushback but I did end up with an 11% readjustment.

Hope those tricks work out for you as well.